# Is it possible to get the created date of Mongodb record in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have recently started to work over mongoDb. I am a MySQL guy and new to NoSQL database. Is it possible to get the record inserted date in MongoDb? How to get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480134/inserting-date-in-to-mongodb-through-mongo-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. First of all welcome to NOSQL. You can get it from the MongoId of the record inserted into the database. By JavaScript you can do this.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var date = dateFromObjectId("57c96f39bb2e40383d000063");
        console.log(date);
   });

   var dateFromObjectId = function (objectId) {
   var week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

   var date = new Date(parseInt(objectId.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
                var ndate = formatDate(date) + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds() + ' Its ' + week[date.getDay()] + '. Month\'s Last Date is ' + formatDate(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0));
                return ndate;
            };

  var formatDate = function (Date){

                var fDate = Date.getDate() + '/' + (Date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + Date.getFullYear();
                return fDate;

     }
```

You can even do a lot more things with the date you get out of it.

Comment: Its really amazing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy coding...:-)